# Remove all "-min" endings from a batch of jpg or png files

Tags: windows, command-line, filenames

Using the CMD (or some other way) on windows, how can I quickly rename all files `[FILE_NAME]-min.png` to `FILE_NAME.png`?

I know a command like `forfiles /m \*-min /c "cmd /c rename @file @fname.png"` might work, but I cannot figure out how to remove the `*-min*` from it.

Answer (score -2):

If you're happy with third party software, you could use [Ant Renamer](https://antp.be/software/renamer). You can use the string replacement action to replace `"-min"` with `""`